# Switch statement doesn't work with some variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I want to make the Angular2 Pipe which returns different values according to passed variable. The variable `device.display` can be of different type (object or string) and takes only two values `null` and `"dataTime"`.

Component part:

```
<div class="col col-2">{{values[variable.id] | display: device.display}}</div>
```

Pipe:

```
Pipe
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'display'
})
export class DisplayPipe {
    transform(value: any, display: string): string {
        display = String(display);
        switch (display) {
            case 'dateTime': {
                value = value * 60;
            }
            case 'null': {
                value = value;
           }
        default: value = 'abc';
        }
    return value;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that after parsing variable to String it is equal to `"null"` or `"dateTime"`. I checked it with `console.log`.

The problem is the switch statement always returns default value:`"abc"`.

Comment: you need to add `break;` after cases and remove `{}` for case

Comment: add break for each switch.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Try `case: ...caseBody; break;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong Syntax. You don't need brackets in each case, and you forgot the `break;` statement.

Heres an example, on how you build switch case:

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `day = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][new Date().getDay()]`

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct sintaxis for switch:

```
switch (display) {
            case 'dateTime':
                value = value * 60;
                break;
            case 'null':
                value = value;
                break;
            default: 
               value = 'abc';
        }
```

if you dont break on every case, switch will execute all cases, then how you are setting same variable on all cases, the value is the last case default: abc.

Answer (score 0):

If you miss the break statement in Javascript [fall-through condition will happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) so default statement got executed and value is always "abc"